# master/minion alike for https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, session-affinity

We are using https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx on azure kubernetes and I want to set session-affinity for only a few selected endpoints. Other implementations support such a configuration e.g. with master/minion feature. Is there a way to achive this with https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx, too?